# Android compare string with array and remove array index values

Tags: java, android

```
if(responseArr.size()!=0) {
    for(int i=0;i<responseArr.size();i++) {
        if(responseArr.get(i).equals("busy")) {
            stylistId.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

If any values in the array contain the string **busy**, I want to remove the value from the **stylistId** array in that position. In the code above, the **responseArr** array and the **stylistId** array are the same size.

When I try to remove values from **stylistId**, it works fine when the loop executes for the first time. When loop executes the second time, I get **indexOutOfBound** Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the index of some elements in the list changes when you remove an element.  For example, if your list has five elements (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) and you remove element 2, then elements 3 and 4  will  get renumbered so that you have (0, 1, 2, 3) afterwards.

There are many possible solutions to this problem, but one way is simply to traverse `responseArr` backwards.

```
        for(int i= responseArr.size() - 1;i >= 0; i--){
            if(responseArr.get(i).equals("busy")){
                stylistId.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

That way, you'll only be changing the indexes of elements that you've already checked.

Answer (score -1):

Because There are two version of `remove` method.

1. remove element at index
2. remove given element

You need to call second method which return element. So, You can use Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < responseArr.size(); i++) {
      if (responseArr.get(i).equals("busy")) {
            int id = stylistId.remove(i);             //use your type instead of int.
      }
}
```

Comment: Why my Question is Down voted ? Please Correct me If My understanding is wrong.